# page reference not redirecting properly and stripping parameters

Tags: visualforce, pagereference, redirect, reference

I am trying to create a url in my class
it gets created corectly and i am able to see it in debug log
but when i pass it to the pagereference it does not redirect correctly. and it strips the parameters out of the url
this is in my sandbox (Full). Please help.
it should redirect to

```
/merge/accmergewizard.jsp?goNext=+Next+&cid=001b000000Fva5qAAB&cid=001b000000RvToJAAV&cid=001g000000RUAhaAAH
```

but it redirects to

```
/merge/accmergewizard.jsp?cid=001b000000Fva5qAAB&goNext=+Next+
```

please help

Comment: Could you post some of your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can add parameters to your pagereference like this:

```
Pagereference pageRef = new Pagereference('/merge/accmergewizard.jsp');
pageref.getParameters().put('goNext','+Next+');
pageref.getParameters().put('cid','001b000000Fva5qAAB');
```

But looking at your input link you are trying to pass the same variable multiple times (3 times cId). I don't think that will work.
You can try adding it as an array, like this:

```
/merge/accmergewizard.jsp?goNext=+Next+&cid[]=001b000000Fva5qAAB&cid[]=001b000000RvToJAAV&cid[]=001g000000RUAhaAAH
```

As explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string